# Problems with setting up a second monitor on Ubuntu

Tags: multiple-monitors, displaylink

I have two monitors that use a VGA that I want to use with my laptop running Ubuntu, which does NOT have a vga port. I am able to get the monitors to work fine with a Display Link VGA to USB display link adapter on windows, but I can not for the life of me get this to work on ubuntu on the same laptop.

I tried to follow [this tutorial](http://how-to.cc/get-a-displaylink-video-adapter-working-with-ubuntu-12-04) but it failed because it could not find the xserver-xorg-video-displaylink package.

Is it possible for me to use my monitor with my laptop in a dual screen setup? And if so, how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

Were you able to install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink using the following command?

`apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink`

If not, please reply with what error you encountered. You may not have the proper dependencies. Try installing them using:

`apt-get install xinit xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-dev xfonts-base libusb-dev xorg-dev git-core build-essential`

EDIT: In reply to your comment saying that you were still unable to get it to work, the `dmesg` logs seem to indicate it's detecting it. Are you using an nvidia graphics card? Are your graphics drivers all up to date? If it's NVidia, then go to `Applications-->System Tools-->Administration` and choose option `Nvidia X Server settings`. Can you select the other display in those options?

Comment: wow, yea that worked. I am going to reboot and see if It worked. Thanks.

Comment: It did not work

Comment: what error are you encountering?

Comment: The monitor continuous to do nothing. I was expecting this command to at least make the screen green, as I have read about. A possibly significant detail is that as soon as I plug the monitor into the adapter, the default dell screen goes away and is black.

Comment: The monitor is also not recognized in the display menu

Comment: But you were able to fully install xserver-xorg-video-displaylink, correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24336/discussion-between-synergist-and-bs7280).